# Find a basis for $W^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ the subspaces of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ formed by all matrix such that 
the sum of their rows is equal to zero. 
Find a basis for $W^\perp$.

$W=\{A\in Mat_n\mathbb({R}):a_{11}+...+a_{1n}=...=a_{n1}+...+a_{nn}=0\}$

$f\in W^\perp\iff f(A)=0\iff f_1(a_{11}+...+a_{1n})=0,...,f_n(a_{n1}+...+a_{nn})=0 \iff f_1(0)=0,...,f_n(0)=0$

Here i'm a little stuck to find a basis for $W^\perp$. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ be the linear forms *sum of the $k$-th row*
$$\varphi_k(A) = a_{k,1}+\cdots+a_{k, n}$$
Obviously, $A\in W \Rightarrow \varphi_k(A) = 0$, hence $\varphi_k\in W^\bot$. Let $S = \text{Span}(\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n)\subset W^\bot$,
then $A\in S^\bot \Longleftrightarrow \forall k\in [1,n], \sum_j a_{k,j}=0
\Longleftrightarrow A\in W$. Hence $W^\bot = (S^\bot)^\bot = S$ and $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ is a basis of $W^\bot$.

Edit: Let us recall the definition of $S^\bot = \{A \in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})\ | \ \forall \alpha \in S, \alpha(A) = 0\}$.

Edit2: Remark that the forms $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k$ are independent because if for $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\alpha := \lambda_1 \varphi_1+\cdots+\lambda_n\varphi_n = 0,$$
then one has $0 = \alpha(E_{k,k}) = \lambda_k$ where $E_{k,k}$ is the matrix which all terms are $0$ but the $k$-th term on the diagonal which value is $1$.

Comment: Who is $M$ here?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $W$

Comment: Good morning Griboullis, I'm a little confused in this part of your proof. $A\in S^\perp$. $A$ is a matrix, how can be in a set of linear functions???

Comment: $S$ is a set of linear functions (a subset of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})^*$). Hence $S^\bot$ is a set of matrices. I'm only saying that for any matrix $A$, one has the equivalence $A\in S^\bot \Leftrightarrow A \in W$. It means that $S^\bot = W$.

Comment: Yor definition of $S^\perp =\{A\in W| \alpha_k(A)=0 \forall \alpha_k \in S\}$? Thanks for all Gribouillis, thanks for take the time of explain (:

Comment: See my edits above.

Comment: $span(f_{1},...,f_{n})\subset W^{\perp}$ For see this, is correct make this? Let $g\in span/f_{1},...,f_{n})$ then $g=af_{1}+....+af_{n}\Rightarrow g(A)=af_{1}(A)+...+af_{n}(A)=0$ in consequence $span(f_{1},...,f_{n})\subset W^{\perp}$ And the last question!!! This part... is little confused to me $0 = \alpha(E_{k,k}) = \lambda_k$ who is $\alpha$?

Comment: You need $g = a_1 f_1 + \cdots + a_n f_n$. In the last part, $\alpha$ is the linear function $\lambda_1 \varphi_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n \varphi_n$.

Answer (score 1):

There is some ambiguity in what "sum of their rows" means. To me, it means you take all the row vectors in $A$ and add them together to get another row vector, and the condition is that this sum must be the zero vector; equivalently, we are taking the sum of each column and checking that it is zero.
The way you interpreted this phrase (as "sum across each row") is essentially the same up to some transposing. For simplicity **I will follow your notation**, but I feel that the intended meaning is the other way.

I will also assume the inner product on this vector space is the trace inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^\top B)$, which can also be viewed as the usual Euclidean inner product if you vectorize $A$ and $B$. If this is not the case OP, you should specify what does orthogonality mean to you.

---

The definition of $W$ actually already contains your answer.
You can check that if $A \in W$, then the $n$ linear constraints
that define $W$ can be written as "$A$ is orthogonal to the following matrices."
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 1\\
0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\ldots,
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
,$$
i.e. matrices that are all zeros except for a single row of $1$s.

So $W^\perp$ definitely contains these matrices. See if you can verify that actually these $n$ matrices are enough to form a basis for $W^\perp$.
It may help to think of $W$ as the nullspace of the linear transformation $T : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that maps a matrix $A$ to the vector containing the row sums. Then $W^\perp = (\text{nullspace}(T))^\perp = \text{rowspace}(T)$.

Comment: Thanks angryavian. Very thanks for take the time to explain me. My definition of $W^\perp=\{f\in V^*|f(v)=\forall v\in W\}$

Comment: @Bvss12 Oh ok, you know what a dual space is. Then you should be able to formalize what I have written into that kind of language.

Comment: @Bvss12 Specifically, the basis of $W^\perp$ are the linear functionals defined as componentwise-multiplication with one of the $n$ matrices I have written above, which is simply the functional that returns one of the row sums.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{J}_{n\times 1}$ be the vector whose every element is $1$. Then $W=\{A\in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})~|~A\mathbb{J}_{n\times 1}=\mathbf{0}\}$. Then $A(\mathbb{J}_{n\times 1}[c_1~c_2~\cdots~c_n])=0$, for $c_1\cdots.c_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $J_i\in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the matrix whose $i^{th}$ column is $\mathbb{J}_{n\times 1}$. Then the basis for $W^{\perp}=\{J_1,\cdots,J_n\}$